# Wrong value from TAN(X) in Python and Excel

Tags: python, math

How can I get the correct value of TAN(X)?

Suppose TAN of 27.2.

**Expected**: `0.51301`, as correctly given by the scientific calculator

**Instead** languages like Python or even Excel give `-1.8459788894`

**I tried** converting `-1.845979` with `rad_to_deg` then I get `-105.7668`.
I also tried converting `-1.845979` with `deg_to_rad` which results in `-0.0322184`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have adapted your question to make it easier to read. Have a look [here for a guide on how to best ask questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18616/164313). In my opinion, it usually helps to keep the three points 1) desired/expected behavior 2) what you get instead 3) what you tried to fix it -- in mind while posting the question. A good visual distinction between the different parts of information helps you get good answers more quickly.

Comment: Thanks **_phant0m_** for small guide, I am new here. :), it's nice website, i got my answer in **less than 10 min.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to convert the *angle* to radians, not the result which is unitless.

```
tan(deg_to_rad(27.2))
```

*27.2°* are *0.4747 radians*: [tan(0.4747rad)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%280.4747rad%29)

Comment: @sachinpore: click the tick next to this guys answer to mark it correct

Comment: I am not getting, which tick

Comment: Nice, I did it!, Thanks again **phant0m**, nice to meet you!